# Url.Action parameters(string)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This is a part of my jQuery in a view in MVC3.

```js
function GetList(ii, href) {
    var toataSucursala =  $("#ToataSucursala").is(':checked');
    var IdAccessLevel = $("#IdAccessLevel").val();
    var InclusivDescendents = $("#InclusivDescendents").is(':checked');
    var numeAsigurat = $("#NumeAsigurat").val();
    var prenumeAsigurat = $("#PrenumeAsigurat").val();

    //console.log("IdAccessLevel: " + IdAccessLevel);
    //console.log("InclusivDescendents: " + InclusivDescendents);

    if (ii != 0) {
        var s = "@Url.Action("PoliteDeReinnoitGrid", new { ViewBag.User.Id, @expiraInZile = -10, @page = 0})" + "&toatasucursala="+toataSucursala+"&numeAsigurat="+numeAsigurat+"&prenumeAsigurat="+prenumeAsigurat;
        //console.log('URL s: ' + s);
        var joindate = new Date(); 
        //var joindate = $('#DatePicker').datepicker("getDate");
```

`#NumeAsigurat` is a textbox.

The problem is, if I write a two words phrase in the textbox at the time of the post this sends only the first word from that phrase. I added some watches and `$("#NumeAsigurat").val();` has the full phrase that I entered.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, I think you're looking for [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) which would make `foo bar` = `foo%20bar` (properly encoded for a URI).